# How to make an app which will run on API 23

Tags: android

Hi there I am new in android development I am making an app for a device running on API level 23.
Q1-
When I create new app I only have option to select minSDKVersion and Android studio itself select compiled diversion as 30 , which I don't want , I want everything to be API level 23.

Q2- When I make compileSdk as 23 and then if I try to run it I am getting this error-

Android resource linking failed
values-v26.xml

please help

Comment: "When I create new app I only have option to select minSDKVersion and Android studio itself select compiled diversion as 30" -- always set your `compileSdkVersion` to the latest production version of Android (right now, `30`). The primary exception is if you are testing a preview edition of Android (e.g., `compileSdkVersion 'android-S'` right now). `compileSdkVersion` does not affect what versions your app can run on.

Comment: There's no reason to use lower `compileSdk` version, if you ever wanted to for unknown reason you'd need to use legacy android studio and old versions of libraries that also have low compileSDK version which is just not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Q1- You can choose what API will be targeted when create a new Project, after that you should download 23 SDK manually in `Android Studio - Tools -> SDK manager -> Android SDK ->` find API 23 and download it.SDK tools also can be found here
Still not sure why you need so old API.

Q2 - with API 23 you should use v23

You build Gradle should looks like that

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.someapp"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```